# One symptom disease, what would it be to make it the most deadly?

Tags: humans, diseases

I am trying to think of ideas for the deadliest disease that kills humans, not other animals. Of course a disease that had no symptoms and started killing people immediately would be the best, but I am looking for a very deadly disease with at least one noticeable symptom. What would the disease and its symptom(s) be?

Comment: Whatever you like? What criteria are you looking for? With your broad problem statement, the symptom could be anything from a runny nose to dropping dead immediately.

Comment: are you asking for a disease with just one and only symptom, at least one, or no symptoms at all? also, an existing one in the real world? or a fantasy one?

Comment: @guido a real or fantasy one. at least one symptom if you read the question

Comment: Symptoms aren't really distinct, discrete things where it makes sense to describe a disease as having exactly one.  For any "symptom" you can identify, you can divide it up into more specific ways of classifying the effects.

Comment: I think you'll find that dying is usually considered a symptom. Aside from that, if you allow fantasy you can pick any symptom you like and just say your disease causes that symptom and no other symptom. If the infected die, you have to explain why though, does their heart stop beating, does their stomach acid leak and burn their innards, does the bacteria eat their brain? Picking this symptom for you is not what we're here for though. You'll need to either pick it yourself and we could help you figure out how it could kill people or you could add more requirements for the symptom.

Comment: This question is broad and seeking brainstorming, which isn't a good fit for this site.  As you can see, it is attracting short "I have this idea" answers without much support or explanation, which is one of the reasons *why* these kinds of questions are not a good fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disease that causes paralysis like a more powerful botulism. One-symptom that also mean your heart get paralyzed or the muscles that allow you to breath.

Answer (score 0):

Itchy feet syndrome- you always feel that you don't fit in so you have to travel. The greatest mechanism for transmission is simple migration. Ebola is contagious without symptoms. Give your illness air-borne transmission and itchy feet syndrome and finally death and it would be the worst pandemic of all time.

Comment: "Ebola is contagious without symptoms." I've heard otherwise; check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_virus_disease#Transmission) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Given that death is the ultimate symptom, you already have your one symptom right there...

But you probably mean one symptom apart from death. Such a symptom should ideally be one that makes the disease more infectious. So coughing, skin rashes, maybe cysts or boils that break and spread the disease agent on touching them. Things like that.

The more innocious the better of course, ideally that symptom should be indistinguishable from other, pretty harmless, conditions in your universe. So if there's regular dust clouds that have people sneeze, sneezing is not seen as a sign that you're infected with that disease, allowing the disease to spread unnoticed until the victims start dropping like flies.